# Authorization Handler

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I have created simple AuthorizationHandler as below:

```
public class IdentityHandler<TRole> : AuthorizationHandler<IdentityRequirement<TRole>>, ITokenValidator
        where TRole : Role
{
    protected AuthorizationHandlerContext AuthContext { get; private set; }              

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PcIdentityRequirement<TRole> requirement)
    {
        AuthContext = context;
        //some checking
        //if no reuqiremnets then call ThrowUnathorizedException()
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual Task ThrowUnathorizedException(string message)
    {
        AuthContext.Fail();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and requirements as below:

```
public class IdentityRequirement<TRole> : IAuthorizationRequirement
        where TRole : Role
{
    public TRole Role { get; }

    public PcIdentityRequirement()
    {
        Role = Activator.CreateInstance<TRole>();
    }
}
```

I have also added the handlers into Startupfile

```
AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy(name, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(requirement)));
```

When requirements are met successfully then everything works fine. However when I do not set `context.Succeed (req)` in `HandleRequirementAsync` then it returns 500 and message:

> No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no
>   DefaultChallengeScheme found.

What should I do there?

Comment: How do you authenticate your users? Have you add `AddAthetication` in your services?

Comment: I do that in my custom middleware where is set claims to HttpContext.User